# Get proper Numbering field for figures in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: formatting, ms-word, ms-office, word-2010

I have .docx document with multilevel list for my chapters and TOC is:

```
1. Chapter One
2. Chapter Two
2.1. Chapter Two, Sub-chapter One
...
5. Chapter Five
5.1. Chapter Five, Sub-chapter One
5.1.1. Chapter Five, Sub-chapter One, Sub-sub-chapter One
etc.
```

I had inserted figure in my sub-chapter 5.1.1. and I used "Insert Caption..." to put some text below the image:

```
Figure 5.1.1.1 Some image caption
```

What I would like to have is caption format where only **Chapter number**, but no sub-chapters numbering is included, like this:

```
Figure 5.1 Some image caption
```

where **5** is my Chapter number and **.1** is sequential of Figure in this Chapter.
Now my field code looks like this:

```
Figure { STYLEREF 1 \s }.{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1 }
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found temporary solution to my problem.
Inside every chapter (denoted by **Heading1** style) I have change the Caption code from this:

```
Figure { STYLEREF 1 \s }.{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1 }
```

to this:

```
Figure 5.{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1 }
```

where **5** is number of my top-level chapter. Then, if I insert new figure, I Copy-Paste above code under it and all figure numbers properly change to new, i.e. sequence number. 
This way, I do not have problems, when executing "Update field" on whole document, where Table of Figures is affected.

Comment: how to avoid to hard code 5? how to make it dynamicaly?

Comment: You can do this: go to `Insert->Links->Cross-reference`, then select `Reference type: Heading`, `Insert reference to: Heading number (no context)` and select heading you are looking for underneath.

Answer (score 2):

In Word2007, all you have to do is be careful to start the sub-chapters with a different heading style.  Then use the chapter heading style for numbering your figures.  Word then ignores your sub-chapters when it numbers your figures, tables, and equations.  Oh, and you have to have the entire document set up as a multi-level list, but it sounds like you've already done that.

p.s.  Although this is a great question, and I learned something answering it, it doesn't really belong on StackOverflow since it isn't a programming question.  Someone will suggest a better StackExchange site for it.  (Super User?)  Don't get mad!  It is *very* easy to open accounts on other StackExchange sites.  Your logon credentials are the same (unless you make them different).  Your reputation doesn't carry over to different sites, but your rep here is only 23 at the moment, so no big deal there.  ;-)  If you move it to Super User, leave a comment here to that effect, and I'll come answer it over there.  Then you can select my answer, and I won't be a 6 there anymore.  LOL!  And maybe you can answer my one question over there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Anyway, I put my question on stackoverflow.com because I felt this WILL BE programming question, if we consider that toggling Field Codes in MS Word in closer to "programming" than average program usage (yes I know, everything less than C is not programming for me too!).